# Git log -- how to retrieve only the latest commits of every file in the git history, where each commit only changes one file

Tags: git, version-control

Arr matey!

Let's say I have 2 files `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`.

Let's say that any time I commit to git, I am only allowed to change one of these files. Therefore I have a commit history where each commit corresponds to a change in either `foo.txt` or `bar.txt`, but not both. **I.e. 1 commit = 1 file change.**

Now let's say I have 4 commits so far, 2 for each of the files. When I do `git log --oneline` I get the following result:

```
hash1 latest changes in foo.txt
hash2 changes in foo.txt
hash3 latest changes in bar.txt
hash4 changes in bar.txt
```

Note: git log returns the latest commits first, so the `hash1` commit is the latest commit for `foo.txt`, and `hash3` for `bar.txt`.

Now what I want to do is return only the latest commits for each file, as per the title, using `git log`. Is there an out of the box filter flag to do that? I.e. I want the output in this case to be:

```
hash1 latest changes in foo.txt
hash3 latest changes in bar.txt
```

In the real thing I have thousands of files and not just two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
git log --oneline -1 <PATH>
```

Combined with `GNU` version of `xargs`, it could be:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -L 1 git log --oneline -1
```

This command would loop through all tracked files in the given repository and execute the above command on each file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with one command but certainly possible with two:

```
git log -1 --grep=foo
git log -1 --grep=bar
```

Create an alias or a shell script to easily call these two commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
git log --grep=bar.txt -1 --oneline && git log --grep=foo.txt -1 --oneline
```

If you have many files, you can add with more `--grep` option.

For thousands of files, you can use a shell script instead (such as test.sh in git repo):

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in $(git ls-files)
do
{
line=$(git log --grep=$file -1 --oneline 2>&1)
echo $line
}
done
```

Then you can execute the script by `./test.sh`.

Comment: For thousands of file, you can use shell script which I added in my answer. You can have a try.